# What's an alternative to "Everything" search for Linux?

Tags: linux, software-rec, file-search

In windows there is a pretty good search tool named [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/), which can let us search files by name. It's very fast, and easy to use.

Now I wonder if there is any similar tool in Linux? Command line or GUI are both fine, but the most important thing is fast.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're just looking for file names, `locate` is pretty standard on Linux systems, although your distro might not have it installed by default.

```
$ locate vmlinuz
/vmlinuz
/vmlinuz.old
/boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-28-generic
/boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-30-generic
```

`locate` relies on a database of existing files which is normally updated nightly by a cron job, so its results are more-or-less instant.

If you need up-to-the-second results, you can instead use `find`, but it will take a while because it goes through the filesystem reading and examining every file present.

```
$ find / -name \*vmlinuz\*
```

will eventually return the same results, plus many "permission denied" errors if you're not running it as root.  Note that the first argument to `find` is the directory to look in (including subdirectories), so you can limit it to only a part of the filesystem to speed things up considerably if you have some idea of where the target file(s) might be.

Comment: Everything uses the journal and changelog of NTFS to locate the files almost instantly. Find is extremely slow compared to that. So what he needs is probably some version of locate coupled with something hooked to the ext3/4 journal. Not sure if anyone bothered.

Comment: what @D.Iankov said is crucial. the advantage of Everything/Swiftsearch/Ultrasearch/similar lies in the fact that they operate directly on the $MFT / USN Journal. i've not been able to find an actual Unix alternative by far

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: I finally ended up very satisfied with Mate desktop with its build in  Search Tool (mate-search-tool fork of [gnome-search-tool](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/gnome-search-tool/)) . It is called directly from mint-menu.To search on all drives I just had to set auto-mounting to drives and update values in the dconf - see help of search tool.

OLD:
After trying Searchmonkey, Locator, locate the best so far is [Launchy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/launchy/) . It is instantly fast with maybe too kompact UI

Answer (score 0):

I have just released a UI front-end for "locate":

https://github.com/AlexTuduran/Locator/releases

Hope that helps.